# mySql timeslots for each day?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, database

I am in the process of developing a new room booking system, Everything has gone ok so far but now I have ran into a problem and I can not seem to find an answer.

The rooms can be booked out between 8:30am and 10:00pm everyday of the week. I have created the pages for creating the new customers and the booking and I'm now just trying to create the part where I check if the date and time is available.

```
    timeId    timeSlot    room1      room2      room3
    1         08:30:00    Available  Available  Available
    2         09:45:00    Available  Available  Available
    3         09:00:00    Available  Available  Available
    4         09:15:00    Available  Available  Available
    5         09:30:00    Available  Available  Available
```

When the booking is placed it changes `Available` to `Requested` for the room and once this is confirmed by a staff member is will again change to `Booked`.

So my problem is, how do i get this to work for different days? I will need to see the above table for every day.

thanks in advance

Further information:

This is my table which holds the bookings:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS booking;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS booking (
    customerno int(8) NOT NULL,
    bookingno int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    youthCafe varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL,
    inkwellMain varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL,
    inkwellSmall varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL,
    kitchen varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL,
    outsideCatering varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL,
    bookingDateStart DATE NOT NULL,
    timeStart  time NOT NULL,
    timeEnd  time NOT NULL,
    recurFreq varchar(15) DEFAULT "N/A",
    attending int(3) DEFAULT NULL,
    layout varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
    equipment varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    catering varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL, 
    cateringOptions varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
    message varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (bookingno),
    FOREIGN KEY (customerno) REFERENCES customers(customerno)
) ;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If Time schedules are fixed then use this.

```
Table-1
TimeID, Time

Table-2
RoomID, ROom

Table-3
ID, Date, TimeID, RoomID
```

If Schedules are not fixed

```
Table-1
TimeID, StartDate, EndDate, ArrivedTime, DepartureTime

Table-2
RoomID, Room

Table-3
ID, TImeID, RoomID
```

Hope this will solve your problem

```
booking-table
customerno, bookingno, bookingDateStart, timeStart, timeEnd

room-table
RoomID, Room

Relation-table
RelationID, bookingno, RoomID
```

Assuming bookingno is unique.
You can get room occupied by joining (INNER JOIN)  `booking-table` and `relation-table` using `bookingno` based on date. The remaining room will be available.

Comment: the rooms are booked out in 15min timeslots. i can see how your solution would work but i already have a booking table. I have added this to my question for you to view. Thanks

Comment: @FallingStar, Hope the modified answer will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with 3 tables.

timeslots: timeId, timeSlot
rooms: roomId, roomName
bookings:  roomId,timeId,date,status

**Updated to accommodate your question edit**

As you already have a booking  table, you're pretty much there.

1. Replace timeStart and timeEnd with timeslot_id.
2. Add column room_id.

I'm not sure how you're using "bookingDateStart", but this should ideally just be "bookingDate".

It looks like your "booking" table is also trying to accomodate recurring bookings. Move this to a separate table - booking_recurring.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS booking_recurring;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS booking_recurring (
    recurring_id int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    start_date DATE NOT NULL,
    end_date DATE NOT NULL,
    room_id NOT NULL,
    customer_id NOT NULL,
    timeslot_id NOT NULL
PRIMARY KEY (recurring_id),
FOREIGN KEY (customerno) REFERENCES customers(customerno)
FOREIGN KEY (room_id) REFERENCES rooms(room_id)
FOREIGN KEY (timeslot_id) REFERENCES timeslots(timeslot_id)
);
```

Whenever a recurring appointment is made (cronjob, etc?), just insert a row into your "booking" table.

Comment: I already have a table called bookings that takes in all the information of the booking form. does this mean that i am going to have to ammend this table: I have added my bookings table to the question. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by replace timeStart and End with timeSlot. At the moment timeStart and TimeEnd is using a javascript timepicker for the users to select the times they wish to book. Also the user can select more then 1 room per booking. for example they could book rooms 1 and 3 at the same time. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Notes:

1. Your booking table does not contain any information for which room a booking is made.
2. You need a table of Rooms, at least ID => Room description
3. Recurring bookings need handling separately and injecting into the booking table as individual events.

To find if a room is available:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM bookings b 
JOIN rooms r ON b.roomId = r.id
WHERE b.bookingDateStart=$bookDate AND r.id=$roomId
AND ($time > b.startTime AND $time < b.endTime)
```

Room is available if your result is zero for a specified time, otherwise not